# Safari Compatibility Issue

Tags: asp.net, mobile, safari, cross-browser

I have web application running on .net flatform 1.1, runs on windows 2003 server. When I tried to acces the web application in the ipad and iphone it is loaded only master page, and default web page is loading to the browser. I recently migrated my web application to asp.net framework 4.0 and deployed in the windows 2008 server, now it is running perfectly fine in the IE 8, but still I have same issue when I try to browse the site on safari. Can anyone help me sort this out? I really need run this application on ipads.

Thank you

Hareen

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague. There is no magical setting you can apply that will fix all your problems but there are a couple of suggestions to get you started:

- Enable the developer in the Safari settings on your iPad so you can see any errors,
- Use Safari on your pc to test your site,
- Make sure your html is valid, use http://validator.w3.org/ to confirm.

This "ASP.NET Conversion and Migration" page might be helpful too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398858

Comment: thank you for suggestions. I will state my issue again, currently I have web application which is deployed on windows 2003 server and running on .net 1.1 framework. This web application is running on my local network. However, when I try to browse the web application on my ipad I am not able to see its start up page, but I can see the master page is loaded to the browser. The content page (loging page) is not loading to the master page. I recently converted application to .net 4 and deployed on the windows 2008 server as second instance . Still I have the same issue in the safari.

Comment: @user1447382 Repeating your question is not going help: you are not giving us enough _detailed_ information to give you a better answer. If you have a problem with your master page then show some code of your masterpage.